# NN don't evaluate well with back propagation algorithm

Tags: java, machine-learning

I've tried to create a basic NN using the book

"Make Your Own Neural Network" by Tariq Rashid

and using the coding train videos:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XJ7HLz9VYz0&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6aCibgK1PTWWu9by6XFdCfh

and the nn.js class on the coding train git as a reference

https://github.com/shiffman/Neural-Network-p5/blob/master/nn.js

I writing the NN network in java, and I tried just like in the playlist to train the network on XOR after I succeeded in doing a single perceptron.
but for some reason, even though my code is similar to what the book is doing and same in the videos (except in the videos he using JS).
when I train the network for around 500000 times with randomized data set of XOR inputs (total of 4 input [1,0] [0,1] [0,0] [1,1]).

when I giving it to guess after the training the all the 4 options I get results closer to 0.5 than to 1,1,0,0 (the order of the inputs in the test are [1,0] [0,1] [0,0] [1,1])

this is my training function:

```
public void train(double [] inputs, double[] target) {
    //generates the Hidden layer values
    this.input = Matrix.fromArrayToMatrix(inputs);
    feedForward(inputs);
    //convert to matrices
    Matrix targets = Matrix.fromArrayToMatrix(target);

    //calculate the output error
    Matrix outputErrors = Matrix.subtract(targets, output);

    //calculate the Gradient
    Matrix outputGradient = Matrix.map(output, NeuralNetwork::sigmoidDerivative);
    outputGradient = Matrix.matrixMultiplication(outputGradient, outputErrors);
    outputGradient.multiply(this.learningRate);

    //adjust the output layer bias
    this.bias_Output.add(outputGradient);

    //calculate the hidden layer weights delta
    Matrix hiddenT = Matrix.Transpose(hidden);
    Matrix hiddenToOutputDelta = Matrix.matrixMultiplication(outputGradient, hiddenT);

    //adjust the hidden layer weights 
    this.weightsHiddenToOutput.add(hiddenToOutputDelta);

    //calculate the hidden layer error
    Matrix weightsHiddenToOutputT = Matrix.Transpose(weightsHiddenToOutput);
    Matrix hiddenErrors = Matrix.matrixMultiplication(weightsHiddenToOutputT, outputErrors);

    //calculate the hidden gradient
    Matrix hiddenGradient = Matrix.map(this.hidden, NeuralNetwork::sigmoidDerivative);
    hiddenGradient = Matrix.matrixMultiplication(hiddenGradient, hiddenErrors);
    hiddenGradient.multiply(this.learningRate);

    //adjust the hidden layer bias
    this.bias_Hidden.add(hiddenGradient);

    //calculate the input layer weights delta
    Matrix inputT = Matrix.Transpose(this.input);
    Matrix inputToHiddenDelta = Matrix.matrixMultiplication(hiddenGradient, inputT);

    //adjust the hidden layer weights 
    this.weightsInputToHidden.add(inputToHiddenDelta);

}
```

those are the sigmoid functions:

```
private static double sigmoid(double x) {
    return 1d / (1d+ Math.exp(-x));
}
private static double sigmoidDerivative(double x) {
    return (x * (1d - x));
}
```

I'm using this method to calculate the derivative because the network already getting the sigmoid function on the feed-forward process so all I do is calculate the derivative like that.

and this is my guess/ feedforward function:

```
public double[] feedForward(double [] inputs) {

    double[] guess;

    //generates the Hidden layer values
    input = Matrix.fromArrayToMatrix(inputs);
    hidden = Matrix.matrixMultiplication(weightsInputToHidden, input);
    hidden.add(bias_Hidden);


    //activation function
    hidden.map(NeuralNetwork::sigmoid);

    //Generates the output layer values
    output = Matrix.matrixMultiplication(weightsHiddenToOutput, hidden);
    output.add(bias_Output);

    //activation function
    output.map(NeuralNetwork::sigmoid);

    guess = Matrix.fromMatrixToArray(output);

    return guess;
}
```

this is in the main class the data set I'm giving him:

```
NeuralNetwork nn = new NeuralNetwork(2,2,1);
    double [] label0 = {0};
    double [] label1 = {1};
    Literal l1 = new Literal(label1,0,1);
    Literal l2 = new Literal(label1,1,0);
    Literal l3 = new Literal(label0,0,0);
    Literal l4 = new Literal(label0,1,1);
    Literal[] arr = {l1, l2, l3, l4};
    Random random = new Random();
    for(int i = 0 ; i<500000 ; i++) {
        Literal l = arr[i%4];
        nn.train(l.getTruthValue(), l.getLabel());

    }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nn.feedForward(l1.getTruthValue())));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nn.feedForward(l2.getTruthValue())));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nn.feedForward(l3.getTruthValue())));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nn.feedForward(l4.getTruthValue())));
```

but for some reason the outputs look like that:

```
[0.47935468493879807] 
[0.5041956026507048] 
[0.4575246472403595] 
[0.5217568912941623]
```

I've tried changing it to subtract instead of add-on every bias and weights update (cause you need the negative gradient although both in the book and in the videos they use add instead of subtract) meaning changing those 4 lines to subtract:

```
    this.bias_Output.subtract(outputGradient);
    this.weightsHiddenToOutput.subtract(hiddenToOutputDelta);
    this.bias_Hidden.subtract(hiddenGradient);
    this.weightsInputToHidden.subtract(inputToHiddenDelta);
```

those are the 2 main outputs I get:

```
[0.9999779359460259]
[0.9999935716126019]
[0.9999860145346924]
[0.999990155468117]
```

or

```
[1.7489664881918983E-5]
[6.205315404676972E-6]
[8.41530873105465E-6]
[1.1853929628341918E-5]
```

I'm pretty sure the problem isn't in my Matrix class that I've created because I checked it before and all the add, subtract, multiply, transpose and it worked fine.

I would really appreciate if someone could look at this code and help me to figure out the problem

Comment: Once you explained, what you have done ...can you please summarize/highlight the issue once again at the end ???

Comment: the issue is in the end, I train the network 500K times, and the guess function return values closer to 0.5 on all 4 guesses instead of 1,1,0,0 (in this order).

Comment: Are you negating the derivative signs...if you see learning equation there is negative sign along with learning rate and derivative for calculating incremental weights...

Comment: When I'm subtracting the gradient from the weights it like I'm negating the derivative. Then all the test data output get close to 1 with all 4 instead of being 1,1,0,0
But because I calculate using x*(1-x) I add the gradient instead of subtracting and all the answers outputs are close to 0.5

Comment: feedForward(inputs) function call returns the value..but I am afraid it is not being stored in any variable and then you are using output variable and target for calculating error...so surprise to see the output variable is being used to calculate the error which is not the return variable from feedForward... in first place question is how train function utilizing the output variable, which is used in feedForward function ????????

Comment: The data that is changed by the feedForward function in the output and hidden layers is still stored, before I used to call the function I had the algorithm of feedForward written all over again in the training function. But there is nothing different between the output if I write the feedForward function in the train function or just call it. I also tried to store the output of feedForward in a variable using
Output = Matrix.fromArrayToMartix(feedForward(inputs)); 
still the same